# Parse byte array as HTTP object

Tags: java, pcap

In Java, how would I convert a byte array (TCP packet payload from a pcap file) into some kind of HTTP object that I can use to get HTTP headers and content body?

Answer (score 0):

One of the <s>stupid</s> lovely things about Java is a total lack of unsigned types. So, a good place to start would be taking your byte array and converting it into a short array to make sure that you don't have any rollover problems. (16 bits versus 8 bits per number).

From there, you could use a `BufferedOutputStream` to write your data to a file and parse it with one of the Java built-in XML readers, such as JaxB or DOM. `BufferedOutputStream` writes hex directly to a file, and can take an input of an `int, byte,` or `short` array. After you write it out, using the `OutputStream` it should be very simple to parse the HTML out of it.

If you need any help with any of these individual steps, I'd be happy to help.

EDIT: as maerics has pointed out, perhaps I didn't grasp what you were asking. Regardless, writing your byte array with a `BufferedOutputStream` is the way to go in my opinion, and I could still help you build a parser if you want.

Comment: Signed bytes are fine too, you just have to be a little careful in how you use them - such as masking away sign-extended bits when (implicitly) upcasting them to int.

Comment: OP asks about *HTTP request/response* parsing, not HTML.

Comment: @harold has a point. I just like upconverting things to shorts because in the end it requires fewer steps.

Comment: @maerics in that case it's not that different a process. It's just a matter of building a parser to handle it, he still has to write the array somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

JNetPcap can do exactly this.
Here are examples for

- [Opening a pcap file](http://jnetpcap.com/?q=examples/offline)
- [Parsing http](http://jnetpcap.com/?q=examples/advanced/web-image-reassembly) (in the example, we extract an image)

Drawback: parsing http in this library is depracated*, but that doesn't mean it doesn't work

*I can't post anymore links without more reputation. Sorry. You can Google for "jnetpcap http deprecated"